# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. : barcode-scanner

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I try to use the barcode-scanner on my react native app, but a I get this error :
**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

That is the code source of my component :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

class QrCode extends Component {

    render () {
        const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
        const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
                setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
            })();
        }, []);

        const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
            setScanned(true);
            alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
        };

        if (hasPermission === null) {
            return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
            return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <BarCodeScanner
                    onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                />
                {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default QrCode;
```

Comment: react hooks can not be used with class components. Your component should be functional component.

Comment: How do you declare a functional component ?

Comment: Is Good, i find the soluce thank you !

Comment: Please refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)